# Считывание нажатий кнопок громкости и питания

Tags: python, mobile

Пишу на Python программу, для которой надо реализовать управление кнопками volume up, volume down и power. Пробовал сделать через библиотеку keyboard, но выдает ошибку что недостаточно прав, хотя я пробовал запускать программу даже на рутированном устройстве. Как можно сделать эту функцию? Можете предлагать варианты как для рутированного устройства, так и обычного (желательно для обычного). Спасибо!

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, полный текст ошибки, название ОС и среды в которой работаете. Без этой информации помочь вам будет трудно.